# Laravel: Retrieve models form database

Tags: database, laravel, model, pagination

I'm trying to figure out how to retrieve models form the database, however I'm only getting arrays and stdClasses. Can any one advise please?

```
$queryBuilder = DB::table(Note::TABLE);
$dto->applyPaginationRules($queryBuilder);
dd($queryBuilder->get());
```

Another method I have looked at is using the models to retrieve models from the database, however there doesn't seem to be a way of applying filters before retrieving all of the information

```
Note::all();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel Eloquent models should make your life easy when dealing with Database in either reading or writing.

You can refer to this section to become familiar with different methods that can be used to build your query either for where conditions [for filtration] or other things such as pagination.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries

For example, If you have the Eloquent model **Note**, you can build your query as follows [depending on the table columns]:

```
Note::query()->where('title','=','some title')
->where('created_at','>',$now)
->orderBy('title')
->get()
```

The get() method must be called at the end in order to execute the built query and it returns a collection of the records.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got what you meant.

You have a model called "Note" You can get all of the notes stored in the database using

```
Note::all()
```

if you want to apply conditions to this query you can do so:

```
Note::where('column_name', '=' , 'value')->get();
```

if you want to use a method on each object you can do so:

```
//get notes with a conditaion
$notes = Note::where('column_name', '=' , 'value')->get();

foreach($notes as $note){
    $note->MethodName();
}
```

Comment: I don't have a static where function on my model.

Comment: try:`Note::query()->where('column_name', '=' , 'value')->get();`